# Clogged sink supply line

Tags: plumbing, bathroom

We just purchased a home in SW Virginia that was built in about 1963. In the basement, there is a spare bathroom and the supply line coming from the wall for the cold water is so clogged with sediment that it only barely trickles out. I have tried to get a couple different plumbers to come out and look at it, but no one seems to want to come for such a small job… so I figured I’d give it is shot myself. I have limited plumbing knowledge but am otherwise pretty handy.

Is this something that I can blow out with compressed air? Or is there a right way to do this?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: If this is a supply line from a cutoff valve in the sink to the faucet, replace the supply line - they're a few $ at any hardware store.

Comment: Can you tell what the supply line pipe material is (copper, galvanized)? Since it's a basement, are the lines accessible? Why do you think it is sediment vs some other potential problem?

Comment: Please post photos of the supply line and any visible connections.

Comment: first of all , let's diagnose the problem before throwing parts at it. If it were me,  I'd turn off the supply for cold, disconnect the line from the shutoff to the faucet at the shut off  , get a bucket and SLOWLY turn the supply back on.  If it runs at full throttle, then it's clearly the line from the cutoff to the faucet that is clogged.  If the hot does the same thing, it's probably a plugged aerator

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.